# What is the incentive to return?

Tags: hells-kitchen

In Hell's Kitchen, the final episode of the season always has the two final contestants going head to head for a dinner service, but with a twist. They have to choose their teams out of a group of chefs who left earlier in the season.

What is the incentive for these chefs to return and/or perform? I'm strictly asking about contractual obligations/promises. What do they get for returning?

I ask because it's not out of the kindness of their hearts and it looks specifically like the producers choose very carefully the people they bring back. Some are great friends of either of the remaining contestants and some were horrible problems during their stint, so it adds an element of drama. I could see why the friends would come back, but what do the "sore losers" get out of it and what happens if they don't come back?

Comment: I'd love to find the truth behind that too - I've always assumed, aside from contractual obligation &/or Ramsey's team getting all lawyered-up; there's some kind of financial recompense attached to their overall series appearance, which could be withheld until after the Final. No play, no pay ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People agree to be on reality TV shows and TV competitions because they want to be on TV. So the first thing that brings them back is another episode of being on TV.

People also agree to be on these shows because they believe it will help their career. Being part of the small team that helped someone win could definitely help your career. Maybe the winner, or one of the other helpers, will recommend you for a job.

If you feel that you left unfairly, or that the producers have edited things to make you look worse than you are, this appearance can be your "redemption" where you shake hands with your enemy, do something generous, or simply show off how great everything's been since you left.

And finally, it's pretty likely that the contract requires them to come back after elimination if they are invited. They may get paid well for agreeing to appear, or penalized for not agreeing to it.

Comment: I'm thinking you're not taking [Elise](http://hellskitchen.wikia.com/wiki/Elise_Wims) into account here ;-)  I'm really not sure she did *anything* to help her career. I wouldn't employ her to flip burgers, I don't care how well she can cook. [OK, I admit, Ramsey is my guilty pleasure; the only reality TV I ever watch]

Comment: She totally fits under the first paragraph. More screen time can be a powerful motivator.

Answer (score -3):

It's all a lie. Or how to put in TV words "carefully planed event".

Imagine that those chef's are Alec Guinness. He read the script and his character dies in the middle of the movie. But he later reprise his role acting as blueish ghost.

This is the same case. Those people know from the start that they will get eliminated at some point. And reason for them would be being evil, falling anus or family member dying from mysterious disease that force them to leave the show.

I think Ru Pauls Drag Race made fun out of this when they dramatized the fact that eliminated competitor get info from Ru Paul that he will come back in the end for more drama.

Comment: "falling anus"?

Comment: @OrangeDog In one of the syndicated "talent show" there was a guy whose tragic backstory was falling anus

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Surely there's a more elegant way of wording your proposed thoughts w.r.t. what OrangeDog brings to light, than what you currently have..